# Two sections for UITableView from NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a collection of Core Data entities. I want to split it into two sections by property *n* of integer type. But the first section should include entities with *n* 0 and the other one include all entities either *n* is 0 or 1. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: That does not really make sense. Should objects with "n == 0" be in the first section or in the second section?

Comment: objects with "n == 0" should be in both sections and objects with "n == 1" should be only in the second sesctions

Answer (score 0):

With a single FRC this will be very hard and inefficient to do this kind of separation.

You will need to edit both the view logic (add supporting structure to the filtered section (n == 0) and the FRC logic (change index paths).
In addition, you will have to scan the entire dataset to decide whether an object in the result set should also be displayed in the filtered section.
this will force you to fault in the entire dataset (at least on load).

I would try a different approach and use 2 FRCs:
main: holds (n == 0 OR n == 1)
filtered: holds (n == 0)

This will force you to tweak around with your view logic since the index paths passed to the FRCs and table view should be adjusted:
 
*each FRC will have only 1 section, while the table view will always have 2
*index paths returned in FRC delegate methods should point to the right section in the table view.

also, you might want to perform the fetch on both FRCs on view load.

You could take a look at an example [here](https://gist.github.com/infradust/7010837).